# Get relative position with extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

What's the proper way to get the position of an element on the page relative to the document?

offsety/x is the jquery variant:  http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset

**I need the EXTJS variant please.**

**Edit**

Possible problem.
Because grid components are not part off the dom, the grid height is not taken into
consideration. I think I need a callback on the reload function off the grid, but I don´t yet know how to do that.

Comment: a little fanatic on the editing?

Comment: Not useful tags, Richard. Too broad.

Comment: You are using opposite logic, javascript is broad, document is narrowing it down! Tags are not just about code language. Those ment to be keywords of ones posting. If I where to search by the tag javascript, I would get problably 90% off the postings done around here.So please don´t do that.

Comment: I mean if you can combine those tags and maybe that's how the searchbox works, instead of a full text search!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each component has `getEl()` method, that will return `Ext.Element` object. This in turn has `getXY()`,`getX()` and `getY()` methods (as well as several others that might be useful for you)

Comment: I have just a div(no components), so I use Ext.get(´footer´)

Comment: `Ext.get()` returns `Ext.Element` objects as well

Comment: getY() is not usefull in this way, it´s the same as getTop(). I does not take the document into account. jquery offset gives me 680 and getY() will give me 400?

Comment: getX/Y() return page coordinates.  getTop() returns page coordinates unless you pass true as an arg, then it's local coords.  If the coordinates are not correct you must have some other issue.

Comment: Thank you,bmoeskau, I have read more answers from you on other posts with Extjs. The solution to this post was to use a callback.The real problem is related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864973/ext-js-problem-setting-height-dynamicly-of-a-grid-when-autoheight-is-already-set Could you please take a look at that one.