# Ext js problem setting height dynamicly of a grid when autoHeight is already set

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I am trying to toggle the height off a grid when the initial setup has autoheight is true.
I want to be able to toggle the height when the grid becomes bigger then the browser view.

The grid is on a normal page without an ext viewport.

If I try setting a height like this, then I loose the scrollbar.
**I can see in firebug that the overflow is set to visible instead off auto.**
How can I change that?

```
mygrid.autoHeight=false;
mygrid.setHeight(200);
```

If I leave autoHeight is true out of the initial setup of the grid, I have no way to determine the height it needs for the rows.

Does anyone possibly have a solution/workaround for this problem?

Thanks in adv, Richard

**EDIT**

I think this will work

```
var scroller = Ext.select("#grid-rekovz div.x-grid3-scroller");
scroller.setStyle('overflow-y','auto');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you leave autoHeight to true, when the data is loaded and doLayout is called the grid will resize to fit all the rows, will it not? It does in all of mine...(though I know "It works for me" is the most unhelpful response ever!)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `autoHeight:true`; then you delegate height calculating problems to browser, so you lose control of it. If you use `autoHeight:false`; then you can change height as you wish, but browser will not added scrollbar to content if it became larger than assigned area.